# The Thom spectrum of the stable framing tangential structure is the sphere spectrum

Tags: algebraic-topology

where a stable framing is a stable tangential structure $\mathcal{X} = EO \to BO$ (ref. Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture9.pdf) Exercise 9.50).  This is Exercise 10.32 in Dan Freed's [notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture10.pdf) and I have no idea to get started with the proof.  Could somebody sketch the main ideas and steps?

Comment: You should ask this question at Mathoverflow.

Comment: @studiosus: why?  My recent posts were knocked down by the mathematicians there hardly so I dare not to post questions there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Thom prespectrum" consists of spaces like $EO(n)^{S(n)}$ in each level.  Each base space $EO(n)$ is contractible, so any vector bundle over it is trivial.  The Thom complex of a trivial bundle is an iterated suspension of the base space.  This gives you spheres (up to homotopy) in each level.  Then it's just a matter of checking that the bonding maps are what you'd expect them to be.

Comment: "The Thom complex of a trivial bundle is an iterated suspension of the base space." That is the key!  Many thanks for the idea, JHF!